# Runtime multiple inheritance with impromptu-interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, runtime, multiple-inheritance, impromptu-interface

I'm trying to get runtime multiple inheritance to work using impromptu-interface but I'm stuck when I want to pass the object along to a method.

```
public interface IEngine {
    void Foo();
}

public interface IWheels {
    void Foo();
}

public interface IChassie {
    void Foo();
}

public interface IPaintShop {
    void PaintWheels(IWheels wheels);
    void PaintChassie(IChassie chassie);
    void ChromeEngine(IEngine engine);
}

var paintShop = Impromptu.ActLike<IPaintShop>();
var car = Impromptu.ActLike(new [] {typeof(IEngine), typeof(IWheels), typeof(IChassie) } ); 
// dynamic car = Impromptu.ActLike(new [] {typeof(IEngine), typeof(IWheels), typeof(IChassie) } ); // Same error 
paintShop.PaintWheels(car); // RuntimeException as car is dynamic and not the expected IWheels
```

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException : The best
>   overloaded method match for
>   'MyStuff.PaintWheels(IWheels)'
>   has some invalid arguments

I've tried to cast but get `InvalidCastException`:

```
paintShop.PaintWheels((IWheels)car);
```

> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type
>   'ImpromptuInterface.ActLikeCaster' to type
>   'MyStuff.IWheels'.

The following works but I'm not sure this is the correct way; it seem unwarranted to convert car to `IWheels` when `IWheels` interface should already be inherited:

```
var wheels = Impromptu.CoerceConvert(car, typeof (IWheels));
paintShop.PaintWheels(wheels);
```

What is the correct way of achieving runtime multiple inheritance using impromptu-interface?

Comment: What does the `ICar` interface definition look like?

Comment: @AGB I've added it now. Not much in this example.

Comment: Do you mean to have `IEngine`, `IWheels` and `IChassie` unrelated?  You mention they should be inherited in your post, but as written they do not inherit from one another at all.

Comment: @AGB I'm trying to achieve multiple inheritance at runtime. What I'm trying to do would be similar to the following code at compile-time : `abstract class Car : IEngine, IWheels, IChassie { // .. Foo }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues you are running into are all related to type safety--even when using a library like Impromptu, you have to be sure the compiler and the runtime are sure the object you are passing into the method is the type that method requires.

`ActLike<T>` can implement many interfaces, but it only returns a single typed instance of `T`, so without a type that tells the compiler that your instance implements several interfaces, you will be forced to cast to the necessary interfaces.

Also, ImpromptuInterface allows you to *wrap* an object with an interface that informally matches up with the implementation of that object, even if the interface was not formally declared.  As a consumer of that library, you still have to provide the implementations for the library to wrap.

Try something like the following:

```
using System;
using ImpromptuInterface;
using ImpromptuInterface.Dynamic;

namespace Example
{
    public interface IEngine
    {
        void Foo();
    }

    public interface IWheels
    {
        void Foo();
    }

    public interface IChassie
    {
        void Foo();
    }

    public interface IPaintShop
    {
        void PaintWheels(IWheels wheels);
        void PaintChassie(IChassie chassie);
        void ChromeEngine(IEngine engine);
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ps = new
            {
                PaintWheels = ReturnVoid.Arguments<IWheels>(wheels => wheels.Foo()),
                PaintChassie = ReturnVoid.Arguments<IChassie>(chassie => chassie.Foo()),
                ChromeEngine = ReturnVoid.Arguments<IEngine>(engine => engine.Foo())
            };
            var paintShop = ps.ActLike<IPaintShop>();

            var fullCar = new
            {
                Foo = ReturnVoid.Arguments(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello World!"))
            };

            var car = fullCar.ActLike<IEngine>(typeof(IChassie),typeof(IWheels));

            //each of these 3 calls prints "Hello World!" to the console
            paintShop.PaintWheels((IWheels)car);//need to tell the compiler to cast your car to type IWheels because var car is of type IEngine
            paintShop.PaintChassie(car as IChassie);//need to tell the compiler to cast your car to type IChassie because var car is of type IEngine
            paintShop.ChromeEngine(car);//works sans cast because var car is of type IEngine

            //each of these 3 calls prints "Hello World!" to the console, too
            dynamic dynamicCar = car;
            paintShop.PaintWheels(dynamicCar);//by using dynamic you disable the compile time
            paintShop.PaintChassie(dynamicCar);//type checking and the compiler "trusts you" on the typing
            paintShop.ChromeEngine(dynamicCar);//since Impromptu wrapped your object and implemented the interfaces for you, there is no runtime exception

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but `public interface ICar : IChassie, IWheels, IEngine` as in your code would mean compile-time multiple inheritance and not run-time.

Comment: Updated my answer to remove `public interface ICar : IChassie, IWheels, IEngine{}`

Comment: Thanks. Seems fullCar can be any object also, no real need for anonymous.

Comment: Yeah, that seems correct to me. I am not really familiar with ImpromptuInterface library, but the documents mention the ability to wrap any object, POCO, or dynamic, so I would presume as long as there was enough of an informal implementation of the interface you are trying to implement, you would be good to go.